# After I upload my image it doesnt get added into the folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I am creating a function so that you can upload an image and I want the image you selected to be stored in a folder on the same domain.

When I try the code below and upload an image I succesfully get "Image Succesfully Uploaded!" but the image does not get added inside my folder: "MyMap/MyPhotoMap/$image_name".

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" >
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        if($image_name==''){
            echo "You forgot to select an image. Please choose one!";
            exit();
        }
        else 
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "MyMap/MyPhotoMap/$image_name"); 
        echo "Image Succesfully Uploaded!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is your current file path and what is folder location `MyMap` ? Also try by providing permission 755 to the folder

Comment: Check what is returned by `move_uploaded_file()` (probably `false`). Also turn on displaying errors because this function should issue a warning when it failes.

Comment: http://myadress.com/MyMap/MyPhotoMap/$image_name this is my full path

Comment: to check what is returned, do i do a print move_uploaded_file(); ?

Comment: I have not done a permission 755 before, is it complicated to add it?

Comment: This would be the issue, you need to provide permission at least 755

Comment: Do i do that in code or do I do it inside my filemanager or somewhere there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="image" >
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" >
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
                $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
                $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

                if($image_name==''){
                    echo "You forgot to select an image. Please choose one!";
                    exit();
                }

                    if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "MyMap/MyPhotoMap/$image_name")); {
                echo "Image Succesfully Uploaded!";
            }
     else{
          echo "Image not uploaded" ;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: it does not accept this line "if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "MyMap/MyPhotoMap/$image_name"); {
                echo "Image Succesfully Uploaded!";
            }"

Comment: When i run the http adress with that code the submit button does not appear

Comment: Yeah, I add to add an addiotional ")" on the move_uploaded_file. so now when I upload something I get "Image not uploaded". If I read one of the comments above it might have something to do with permission 755 to a map? I have never heard of this before. Is it something you do in code?

Comment: This together with changing the map to permission 755 made it work! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need proper braces;

```
if($image_name==''){
echo "You forgot to select an image. Please choose one!";
exit();
}
else { // add braces for else part
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "MyMap/MyPhotoMap/$image_name"); 
echo "Image Succesfully Uploaded!";
}
```

Comment: This won't change anything. The file still won't be uploaded.